# Dart compare int null safety issue : operator can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable, dart-null-safety

I have an object of class `State` it contains a nullable list called playList and a nullable  player object.

when I try to write this if statement

```
if(state.playList?.length > 0 && state.player?.currentIndex? >0)
```

I got this error

> The operator '>' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver
> can be 'null'

I solved this issue by writing two nested if statement

```
if(state.playList != null && state.player?.currentIndex !=null)
{
    if(state.playList!.length > 0 && state.player!.currentIndex! >0 )
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

How to rewrite the above code in better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
if((state.playList?.length ?? 0) > 0 
 && (state.player?.currentIndex ?? 0) > 0)
```

But if you want to work with those values later on, you need to put them in local variables, otherwise you will have to add countless `!` as you have experienced in your second example.

As an example of how to "get rid" of the nullability later on by using local variables that will be "promoted" to their non-nullable type after the check:

```
final playList = state.playList;
final currentIndex = state.player?.currentIndex;

if(playList != null && currentIndex != null)
{
    if(playList.length > 0 && currentIndex > 0)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I feel it isn't readable `if((state.playList?.length ?? 0) > 0 
 && (state.player?.currentIndex ?? 0) > 0)` Not sure if there is a more readable solution.

thank you